# What happened to "Roll up" option in Preferences/Window/Title bar Action?

Tags: window-manager

I like very much the option "Roll up" in Preferences/Window/Title bar Action but it is not there anymore in 10.10.

There are a way to get it back?

Answer (score 5):

open up the [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor) and go to `apps/metacity/general/action_right_click_titlebar` and change it to `toggle_shade`

of course you need metacity running as your window manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Tweak Ubuntu to set the window decorations.