# How to "roll up" the window?

Tags: 11.10, window-management, titlebar

After just having upgraded to 11.10, I wonder how i can change what happens when I double click a window title bar. I had it configured to roll up (I cannot remember the phrase in English, in German it was "einrollen", i guess) which was found in the appearence menu as far as a I remember.

The solution proposed at [What happened to "Roll up" option in Preferences/Window/Title bar Action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6882/what-happened-to-roll-up-option-in-preferences-window-title-bar-action) doesnt work for me insofar as toggle-shade minimizes the window with a roll-up animation, and shade alone will maximize the window after rolling it up.

Anyone have a clue what i can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to "Roll up" option in Preferences/Window/Title bar Action?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6882/what-happened-to-roll-up-option-in-preferences-window-title-bar-action)

Comment: Unity doesn't seem to have this function by default , but it does exist in blackbox and openbox desktop environments. Try them out maybe

Answer (score 3):

Run in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/gwd/mouse_wheel_action shade
```

This will fix it on Ubuntu 11.10 for those using Unity.

Answer (score 3):

Use Ubuntu-Tweak to do this:

[image]

For instructions on how to install Ubuntu-Tweak:
[How do I install Ubuntu-Tweak?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Comment: please read previous posts of me and others before posting solutions.

Comment: @Dominik: ????? Are you using Gnome **Shell** and not Unity (if so you didn't mention it and your down vote is unfair). Point me to what I'm missing btw. You haven't done so.

Comment: I am using Unity, as written above.

Comment: @Dominik: so then, what did I miss?

Comment: RolandTaylor apparently the fact that there is an answer in the [post linked](http://askubuntu.com/a/61498/34049) *which may as well not exist as yours is superior* is enough for a downvote for your question. @Dominik, the answer deserves an upvote and a note saying 'unfortunately this did not work for me, but good answer!', not a snarky remark and a downvote. Remember, Roland is taking time out of his day to freely attempt to help you with your issues. A little respect where respect is due please.

Comment: I am truly sorry, I see my failure. I was a bit unpleased to see new answers that do not really help (and indeed it does not for me, since my request is five months old and no more important). I want to thank for the screenshot. Damn, I cannot talk myself out of this, sorry for overreacting.

Comment: @Dominik: :P apology accepted :D

Comment: puh! i sometimes do not know how to behave :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNOME Shell, install gnome-tweak-tool :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then launch it, go to Windows and set up whatever you want.

[image: Gnome-Tweak-Tool]

Comment: Thx, but that doesnt seem to work. Anyway, i do not need this so urgently so i'll just let it go. Besides, it looks quite different on Unity, i believe you use it on gnome-shell?

Comment: I've tried the advice given here and elsewhere.  While I'm able to set the appropriate property to toggle_shade, it has no effect and applications will maximize, disappear, or do nothing upon double clicking the title bar.

Comment: Sorry, it probably only work if you are using GNOME Shell. For Unity the option will probably be in CCSM.

Answer (score 0):

**** Just noticed you specifically mentioned this method doesn't work for you. Sorry about that!

To roll-up a window when you double click on the title bar, all you have to do is change existing preferences without the need to install any extra software just for this one feature.

**SYSTEM > PREFERENCES > Windows > Select "Roll Up" on the Titlebar Action Menu**

This worked for me with Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: true - but on 11.10 and gnome 3 that option disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 13.04** To toggle shade with mouse wheel on title bar (w/gnome fallback here, not sure if this works in standard installed unity)

- Use dconf editor to  change
- org.compiz.gwd mouse-wheel-action none
- to
- org.compiz.gwd mouse-wheel-action shade

Answer (score 0):

v13.10 (flashback)

dconf

org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences

- action-double-click-titlebar
- action-middle-click-titlebar
- action-right-click-titlebar