# How to link inserted images by default in LibreOffice writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I often have to deal with documents using multiple images -- as e.g. Howtos, short documentations, or even books with many examples. Always when I start a new document with LibreOffice Writer and insert the first pictures, they are *embedded* by default. I need them to be *linked* by default -- but could not find a suitable setting. Can anybody tell me where that's hidden? I know it was possible with StarOffice 8, which I used before upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04.

In other words (to be clear from the beginning): How do I tell LibreOffice to *always* default to *link* inserted images instead of embedding them?

Comment: This isn't possible with LO right now, AFAIK, but it might be a good idea to ask [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/) as well. I will gladly chime in if you choose to create a feature request on [LO's bug tracker](https://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/bug/).

Comment: Unfortunately, that again requires a separate account. Neither do they provide the possibility to "anonymously" file a bug, nor permit using some existing like the ones we have here :(

Comment: I agree. It's annoying that each project has their own bug tracker and Q&A, [but such is the reality in the open-source world](http://xkcd.com/927/). Unfortunately there's no way around that if you want your problem solved. I would file a bug report myself but I am very short on time right now and I am already maintaining too many reports.

Comment: Not an answer, but a very quick workaround is using Ctrl-Shift-V, it will ask you HOW you want to paste the image.

Comment: That's the other way around. I usually pick the images to be linked from the file system, not embedding them via copy-paste from some graphics editor or the like. Chosing "bitmap" would embed it -- I want to link it. But I will check for those options as soon as I'm back home, thanks!

Comment: @GerhardBurger That doesn't seem to work for me. I get a selection window with only one option: "unformatted text". But that only pastes the image's path. What LO version are you using where this works?

Comment: [I cross-posted this question to AskLibreoffce](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/15363/how-do-i-link-inserted-images-by-default-in-writer/) and I advise everyone interested in this feature to vote for it.  You will have to create a new account as AskLO doesn't use stackexchange, but wih OpenID this shoudn't be too much of a problem.

Comment: Just to be clear: if there turns out to be no solution I will file a feature request and post it here. I hope for your participation and support in raising awareness for this issue.

Comment: @MHC do you copy the url or the image itself? you should copy the image.

Comment: @GerhardBurger I copy the image. Maybe we are running different file managers and LO versions? I am using Nautilus and wasn't able to replicate your method neither with LO 3.6.5 nor 4.0.

Comment: @HMC I am copying the image from Firefox, that might be the difference (I'm also using 4.0).

Comment: @GerhardBurger Yep, that's it. CTRL+SHIFT+V seems to only work with remote locations.

Comment: @GerhardBurger [Seems as though CTRL+SHIFT wasn't so wrong after all](http://askubuntu.com/a/275773/81372)

Answer (score 7):

@manj_k over at AskLibreOffice was kind enough to let me repost his [answer](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/15363/how-do-i-link-inserted-images-by-default-in-writer/?answer=15376#post-id-15376) here:

**Current state**

As of this point there is no way of telling LO to link inserted images by default. But this enhancement has been requested, triaged and given a high priority on LO's bugtracker,  so it's on its way:

[Bug 61358 - UI: Remember state of option "Insert image from file -> Linked"](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61358)

If you are interested in this feature and would like to follow its development I would advise you to subscribe to the bug report. Feel free to contribute and comment if you have any ideas on how you would like to see this option implemented.

**Workaround**

The *Insert from File* dialog isn't the only way to link a picture in a document. You can do so as well by dragging and dropping the image in question while holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. Personally, I prefer this workflow as it's faster than the *Insert* dialog. Note: This only appears to be working with LO writer.

Comment: If I had two monitors, this would be a good work-around indeed! But at home, I only have one, and LO I use in full-screen mode (which makes drag-and-drop a little hard, but not impossible having the file manager open as a window to switch to with Alt-Tab, and then drag-n-drop). +1 from me meanwhile -- accept comes later (I doubt there will be a better solution). And thanks for crossing over to ALO and LO's bug reporting, I will follow-up there.

Comment: @Izzy Glad I could help :). As for your single monitor setup, how about this: Resize your file manager to a small enough size and set it to be [always on top](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tELhS.jpg). Then move it to a corner of the screen where it's unobtrusive. Would this work for you?

Comment: To make it take up even less space when unused, you can reactivate the [roll up option](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc8YpvJI_fw). [Here's a tutorial on how to do it.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/67009/how-to-roll-up-the-window) If you are using a different desktop environment this should be even less of a problem as most window managers (Openbox, XFWM, Kwin) support this option natively.

Comment: Thank you, MHC -- and yes, I could use the rollup-option (thanks for that idea I didn't think of). As described, having the FM in "window mode" and switching with Alt-Tab should do for me. I will try this when the next task comes up; currently I'm busy with other things, the books are just done :)

Comment: Unfortunately, after more than 4 years, status of that [Bug 61358 - UI: Remember state of option "Insert image from file -> Linked"](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61358) is still on "NEW" and obviously not being worked on :(

Answer (score 5):

A bit strange, **LibreOffice Writer Help** said **Link** is default option:

> Inserting Bitmaps
>
> ```
>  1. Choose Insert - Picture - From File.
>
>  2. Select the file. In the File type box you can restrict
>     the selection to certain file types.  
>
>  3. Click the Link box if you want a link to the original file.  
>     If the Link box is marked, whenever the document is updated  
>     and loaded the bitmap image is reloaded.
> ```
>
> The editing steps that you have carried out in the local copy of the image in the document are re-applied and the image is displayed.
>
> *If the Link box is not marked, you are always working with the copy created when the graphic was first inserted.*
>
> *To embed graphics that were first inserted as links, go to **Edit - Links**
>   and click the **Break Link** button.*
>
> ```
>  4. Click Open to insert the image.
> ```

---

The way around this workflow also related to using **Gallery** (just a bit faster way):

1. Open **Gallery** pane.
2. Create new "custom" theme.
3. Add any pictures to newly created theme.
4. Use Right Click on picture in Gallery to use menu **Insert > Link**.

Comment: That is funny...  It's certainly not the default option even if I check it..

Comment: :) really very strange program LibreOffice ... maybe you have unchecked "Always Ask" checkbox on the "Keep Link - Embed Bitmap" dialog ... so if your last way is Embed it is logically YOUR OWN defaults, not of LibreOffice ...

Comment: I have to check that box every time I insert an image. Regardless of the last used state, this box always turns up unchecked in this dialog the next time you insert an image.

Comment: Where does it say link is default?