# Can I configure double-click title bar behavior?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to “Roll up” option in Preferences/Window/Title bar Action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6882/what-happened-to-roll-up-option-in-preferences-window-title-bar-action)

Prior to upgrading, I had my system configured so that double-clicking the title bar would roll up the window, just leaving the title bar.

Is this possible with 11.10?  Behavior seems inconsistent - firefox seems to try, but then the titlebar disappears, and that entire set of tabs seems to be gone until I restart; chrome just goes to full screen, while a terminal does nothing.

Is this a parameter that can be configured?  If so, where?